# Very simple AC voltage question

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, voltage-source

How to simplify these two voltage sources (same frequency) into one so I can calculate the current then the power absorbed by each element

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be sure they are at the same frequency? If so, it's a simple phasor sum.

Comment: Yes, we assume they are the same. @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use KVL and represent the sources as phasors:
\begin{align*}
    V_1 - V_2 &= IZ_T\\
    125e^{j(10)} - 150e^{j0} &= I\left(4 + j(4 - 2) \right) 
\end{align*}

From there, just expand and you can solve for the current as well as the power for each element.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know it's that simple, (look at the last image in my post) is it correct?

Comment: @Balawi28 Yep! That looks good to me

Comment: Thanks for your time, hope you have a nice day.